# Elasticsearch 6.4.2 | Graph not able to see anything

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-6, kibana-6

Installed ES 6.4.2 & Kibana 6.4.2.

Installed a trial license using the API on ES.

When I opened the graph workspace on Kibana and loaded my index pattern, nothing actually is shown. Also, the query text field is read only.

Is there any settings I'm missing somewhere? Also, are there any simple examples of Graph in GitHub somewhere?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Once you select the index pattern click on the `+` icon to add the index pattern. Select a field, add it and you should be able to use the query text field